# How to uninstall FileFly?

Tags: 22.04

How to uninstall FileFly WiFi file transfer application? I installed it using command
`sudo snap install filefly` as instructed in this page https://snapcraft.io/install/filefly/ubuntu. I cannot find it in ubuntu software centre or in synaptic package manager. I am using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Comment: Have you tries `sudo snap remove filefly` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can uninstall it by

```
sudo snap remove filefly
```